# Animate.CSS Adding Scroll Bar?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, animate.css

I am using [Animate.CSS](http://daneden.me/animate/) and I am using the "hinge" effect to have an image fall off the screen. When it goes off the screen it adds a vertical scroll bar to the page. When you scroll nothing is visible. Why is this scroll bar being added and how do I keep it from being added?

Thanks!

Code:

**HTML**

```
<img id="animate" class="fear" src="/2012/images/september/fear-sign.png" />
```

**CSS**

```
.fear{
     position:absolute;
     left:150px;
     top:0px;
}

#animate {
    -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    -o-animation-delay: 5s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-delay: 5s;
}
```

**JS**

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
   $j(document).ready(function() {
       $j('#animate').addClass('animated hinge');
           });
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/FafAH/1/) I created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use `overflow:hidden`, that will prevent the scroll bars:

```
html,body { overflow: hidden; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FafAH/2/

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
body{overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set `overflow-y` to hidden to prevent vertical scrollbars and `overflow-x` to hidden to prevent horizontal scrollbars.

```
html, body{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```